# Running tforminv using a loaded TFORM structure

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I use cp2tform and a set of about 100 xy control point pairs to generate a TFORM structure, which I then use to transform xy coordinates between two coordinate systems ("old" and "new"). It works fine. Below is how I convert coordinates x_old y_old into x_new y_new.

```
[TFORM]= cp2tform([x2,y2],[x1,y1],'lwm',16);
[x_new, y_new] = tforminv(TFORM, x_old,y_old);
```

Now I need to save the TFORM structure into a mat file, and load it to do my transforms from old to new, without having to run cp2tform each time. When loaded, the TFORM structure appears to contain all the data needed for the transform (control points etc). However, I get the following error when running tforminv:

```
Error using feval
Undefined function handle.

Error in tform (line ...)
X = feval( t.(f.fwd_fcn), U, t );

Error in tforminv (line ...)
varargout = tform('inv', nargout, varargin{:});
```

I found a post recommending including cp2tform into the function file.

```
%#function cp2tform
```

Tried this, but it did not have an effect. There was a warning about not being able to load it which is strange, as I run cp2tform fine from my local directory just fine.

I can go back to running cp2tform each time, but I wonder if there is a way to use preprocessed data in the TFORM structure. May I ask for help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you saving the variable `TFORM`? The following might work `clearvars;load('data_1.mat');TFORM=cp2tform([x2,y2],[x1,y1],'lwm',16);save('tform.mat','TFORM'); clear; load('tform.mat'); load('data_2.mat'); [x_new, y_new]=tforminv(TFORM,x_old,y_old);` where `data_1.mat` (containing x1, x2, y1 and y2), and `data_2.mat` (containing x_old, and y_old).

Comment: Thank you, Azim. I save TFORM the way you showed, i.e. save('tform.mat','TFORM'). When I load it, it looks like the control points are already included in it. the callback function shows as unknown though. When I load TFORM I get a warning saying it could not be found. I will try changing that to tforminv. For now, I've gone back to transforming each time via cp2tform, w/o saving TFORM.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? With R2020a the following runs without error. 
a=START_SNIPPET;
clearvars; x1 = rand(16,1); x2 = rand(16,1); y1 = rand(16,1); y2 = rand(16,1); TFORM = cp2tform([x2,y2],[x1,y1],'lwm',16); save tform.mat TFORM; 
clearvars; load tform.mat; x_old = rand(5,1);  y_old = rand(5,1); [x_new,y_new] = tforminv(TFORM, x_old, y_old);
%END SNIPPET
can you give me the error code you get when you run the above on your system? Maybe that will give me a clue what might be wrong.

Comment: It's 2018a. I ran your snippet with my saved TFORM. START_SNIPPET x_old = rand(5,1); y_old = rand(5,1); [x_new,y_new] = tforminv(TFORM, x_old, y_old);
Error using feval
Undefined function handle.

Error in tform (line 55)
X = feval( t.(f.fwd_fcn), U, t );

Error in tforminv (line 67)
varargout = tform('inv', nargout, varargin{:});
 
>> a = lasterror

a = 

  struct with fields:

       message: 'Error using feval↵Undefined function handle.'
    identifier: 'MATLAB:UndefinedFunction'
         stack: [2×1 struct]. END_SNIPPET. The same TFORM works if I generate it each time.

Comment: can you run my snippet from an empty workspace. I am wondering if your saved `TFORM` is a struct with the following fields:TFORM

TFORM = 

  struct with fields: ` ndims_in:2; ndims_out:2;  forward_fcn:[]; inverse_fcn:@(varargin)builtin('_inv_lwm',varargin{:}); tdata:[1×1 struct]` and tdata has fields: LWMTData:[6x2x16 double]; ControlPoints:[16x2]; RadiiOfINfluence:[16x1]`. The important thing here is the value of the `forward_fcn` and `inverse_fcn` fields. Let me know what you have and maybe we can go from there.

Comment: You also mentioned that you edited `cp2tform` can you revert to the original version before testing?

Comment: azim, OK, will do. I saved TFORM in whatever "form" :) it was generated by cp2tform. I will go ahead and edit inverse_fcn as you say, as in my case it showed up as 'unkonwn'... I did not edit cp2tform,

Comment: @runcyclexski sounds good. let me know what you have further information otherwise maybe someone else will come along with ideas on how to proceed.